# WordPress As A Shared Items Collection

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-recommendation, post-formats

I'm planning on using WordPress to create an arcive of my starred/shared/favourited items on a few services, such as:

- Twitter Favourites
- YouTube Favourites
- Google Reader Starred Items
- Stack Overflow Starred Questions
- etc.

As the data for each type is different, eg video/article/short text what would be the best way of doing this?  Would a custom post type or format for each type be the best way?

Or does anyone have any suggestions for any themes or plugins which work in a similar way to save me doing all of this from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I would suggest to do it with Post Formats.

Before there were Post Formats, I made [sth similar](http://senl.in/hsLf0z) to what you're looking to do. Although I am not sure whether it is possible to "grab" You Tube Favorites, others should be possible. I actually integrated a lot of social media feeds using the Feed WordPress plugin and Yahoo Pipes where necessary. You can read more on the linked page.

Comment: That looks almost exactly what I want to do, thanks :)